# Searching for a sci fi story from the 50's or 60's, of snail like creatures on another planet spend their lives eating

Tags: story-identification

It may be called The Gleanors, or something.  They each have a strip of land to glean, with neighbors doing the same. the story is hard to remember, but it was totally interesting. When I think back, I can only say that they must have been an excellent writer, to be able to do so much with so little in the story.

Comment: This is likely "On the Fourth Planet" as described in this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36463/short-story-where-creatures-have-squares-of-territory/45888 which sadly does not have an accepted answer (although I believe the answer given is correct).

Comment: And also this question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89227/looking-for-the-title-author-of-story-about-snail-like-creatures which does have an accepted answer.

Comment: I really sounds like " On the Fourth Planet", believe that it is.  Anyone know where I can find this story?

Comment: For a list of places where you can find the story, just click into [the ISFDB page for that story](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44472).

Comment: Also Google has the story, minus a few pages---Carrumba !! Incidentally, I believe this story takes the cake as far as imagery goes, and the way you feel transported and sympathetic to a race of squid/slug type beings.. Mr. Bone is a scholarly man with much imagination and much knowledge of biology and the sciences.

Comment: Fey Ray, since "On the Fourth Planet" seems to be correct, please formally accept the answer below using the checkmark icon near its top left. You are the only one who can do so, and this will assist the moderators in their duplicate management efforts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for a short story title about an alien that encounters a probe on its own planet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187353/looking-for-a-short-story-title-about-an-alien-that-encounters-a-probe-on-its-ow)

Comment: See OP comment above indicating extremely likely match.

Comment: @Otis I think your answer here is better than OrganicMarble's on the proposed dupe target, so I've closed them the other way.

Answer (score 5):

Per the OP comments above, this appears to be "On the Fourth Planet," by J. F. Bone, which was originally published in the April 1963 edition of *[Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Science_Fiction)*. Per ISFDB, it has been [collected several times](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44472), and is legally [available to read](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/50904) in its entirety courtesy of Project Gutenberg.

The story features alien creatures who call themselves "the Ul," with each having a personal name. The protagonist of the story is "the Ul Kworn," who must contend with an unexpected obstacle that threatens him with starvation due to the very precarious balance between the amount of available food and the amount needed to survive. The story does indeed use the verb "to glean" to indicate obtaining food from the land.

> The Ul Kworn paused in his search for food, extended his eye and
> considered the thing that blocked his path.
>
> He hadn't notice the obstacle until he had almost touched it. His
> attention had been focused upon **gleaning** every feeder large enough to
> be edible from the lichens that covered his feeding strip. But the
> unexpected warmth radiating from the object had startled him. Sundown
> was at hand. There should be nothing living or non-living that
> radiated a fraction of the heat that was coming from the gleaming
> metal wall which lay before him. He expanded his mantle to trap the
> warmth as he pushed his eye upward to look over the top. It wasn't
> high, just high enough to be a nuisance. It curved away from him
> toward the boundaries of his strip, extending completely across the
> width of his land.

This story has previously been asked about [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36463/short-story-where-creatures-have-squares-of-territory) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89227/looking-for-the-title-author-of-story-about-snail-like-creatures), having received an accepted answer the second time.